# selection of device in storyboard making difference in UI for iphone x and previous - video player : ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout, iphone-x

Hey Guys I have a strange issue - I am playing a video in video player. Code used for the same is :

```
let url = URL(string: "xxxxxxxxxx.mp4")
    player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resize
    // make the layer the same size as the container view
    playerLayer.frame = self.viewVidioPlayer.layer.bounds

    self.viewVidioPlayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    self.observer = player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
        if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {

            if let currentItem = self.player!.currentItem {
                let duration = currentItem.asset.duration
                print("Total Duration - \(duration)")
            }


            let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
            //print("\(time)")
            print("Intro Video stress Overlay - \(time)")

            let playbackLikelyToKeepUp = self.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp
            if playbackLikelyToKeepUp == false {
                //print("Here start the activity indicator inorder to show buffering")
            }else{
                //print("stop the activity indicator")
            }
        }
    }
```

In the storyboard I have my video view with constraints to superview for top, bottom,leading,trailing and I play the video. The issue here is strange that when I choose storyboard and select iPhone 7 - it works well for iPhone 7 but not iPhone x and when I choose iPhone X and run in iPhone X , it works well but not in iPhone 7. There comes black spaces on the sides. Can anyone explain what can be the issue ? Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: i think because you are adjusting your view according to that screen size. Give your constraints properly it will work in all the devices similarly.

Comment: But I have given constraints as per superview.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an issue that occurs due to the `safe area` of the iPhone X. Try to set your constraints to the `superview` and not the `safe area`.**

I have noticed in one of my projects this issue could also happen if the aspect ratio of your video is not matching to that of iPhone X.To fix this i had different versions of the video designed with the respective aspect ratios of the devices.
I had one version for iPad's, One version for iPhones without the notch and one version for iPhones with the notch. Also try to set your videoGravity to `AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect`

Even if you set the player view to match the bounds of the superview, the frame of the `player` layer will be that of the video's aspect ratio.

You could fix this issue by trying to scale the video layer to that of the frame size. But this will cause ur video to either stretch in width or stretch in height and it will look odd.